# Configuring Squid as a proxy server that allows torrenting

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, bittorrent

I have an Ubuntu 16 server with Squid 3.5 installed. The squid.conf file only has two lines:

```
http_port 1234
http_access allow all
```

Right now I can set this server up as a proxy, and use it to send curl commands and browse the net fine. However, torrenting does not work. When I try to download the [Wikipedia Data Dump](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents) with the qBittorrent client on Windows as a test, only the HTTP trackers successfully connect, none of the UDP trackers. And the torrent doesn't download at all.

I can see in the access logs of squid the connections made by http trackers, and curl commands, but none of the udp trackers or any client connection information is shown in the logs.

I suspect it might have something to do with UDP traffic.

I have gotten other proxies, like PIA, to work fine in qBittorent, but this is the first time I'm making my own.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does Squid have to do with bittorrent? It's an HTTP proxy, and bittorrent doesn't use HTTP. [What are you actually trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Are you confusing a proxy with a firewall?

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. I was confused because torrent clients allow http proxy. I guess that means it doesn't allow most traffic. I decided to use another program, 3proxy. It works fine.

Comment: squid allow bittorrent throught sock5

Comment: qbittorrent v4.1.5 allows me to specify http proxy but it does not run then. Socks support for squid is apparently not builtin in Ubuntu. I am going to try dante socks server instead of squid. (`apt install dante-server`)